# Activar un botón para guardar datos luego de seleccionar en los combobox

Tags: c#, botón, combobox

Para mi proyecto de trabajo de título, estoy con un colega haciendo un sistema de mantenimiento de inventario y ventas para un negocio. Mi consulta es como puedo activar un botón que guarda datos en la Base de datos, luego de seleccionar las opciones que entrega cada combobox (estamos trabajando con 2 combobox para guardar productos, uno de proveedor y otro de categoría). El problema es que estoy tratando cómo programar que el botón Guardar se active después de seleccionar en los combobox, al abrir el formulario me aparece el botón desactivado y se activa al llenar los campos de los textbox cuando quiero que siga desactivado al no seleccionar nada de los combobox. Adjunto código del procedimiento que usé para validar:

```
    private void validarAgregarProducto()
        {
            var valAgregarProducto = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNombreAgregarProducto.Text) &&
                                           !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStockInicialAgregarProducto.Text) &&
                                           !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStockAlertaAgregarProducto.Text) &&
                                           !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPrecioVentaAgregarProducto.Text) &&
                                           !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPrecioCompraAgregarProducto.Text) &&
                                           !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDescripcionAgregarProducto.Text);
// cmbProveedorAgregarProducto.SelectedIndex == -1 && 
// cmbCategoriaAgregarProducto.SelectedIndex == -1;

btnGuardarAgregarProducto.Enabled = valAgregarProducto;

            
        }
```

Ahora Adjunto los códigos de los combobox change:

```
    private void cmbProveedorAgregarProducto_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbProveedorAgregarProducto.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                string[] filaProveedor = resultadoProveedorAgregarProducto(cmbProveedorAgregarProducto.Text);
                ProveedorAgregarProducto_Seleccionada = filaProveedor[0];
            }  
        }

        private void cmbCategoriaAgregarProducto_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbCategoriaAgregarProducto.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                string[] filaCategoria = resultadoCategoriaAgregarProducto(cmbCategoriaAgregarProducto.Text);
                CategoriaAgregarProducto_Seleccionada = filaCategoria[0];
            }
            
        }
```

Toda ayuda será recibida.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Winforms? o Webforms?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, lo que quieres hacer es que el botón de "Guardar" se habilite cuando un valor sea seleccionado en los dos ComboBox que tienes, si es así, puedes poner una validación de la siguiente manera:

Primero capturas el evento de selección de tus ComboBox "Proveedor y Categoria"

```
private void cmbProveedorAgregarProducto_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Código implementado...
        }

private void cmbCategoriaAgregarProducto_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbProveedorAgregarProducto.SelectedIndex == 1 && cmbCategoriaAgregarProducto.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                btnGuardarAgregarProducto.Enabled = true;
            }
            //Código implementado...
        }
```

Como puedes observar, **en el combo de categoría hay una validación para ambos combos dónde se asegura que los dos combos tengan al menos un valor seleccionado** y si esto es verdadero, habilitará el botón de guardado para ser usado

Adicionalmente, cuando termine el proceso de guardado y quieras volver a registrar un producto, seria bueno limpiar ambos combos y deshabilitar de nuevo el botón de guardar. Por ejemplo:

```
cmbProveedorAgregarProducto.Items.Clear(); //Definir el nombre de tu combo
cmbCategoriaAgregarProducto.Items.Clear(); //Definir el nombre de tu combo
btnGuardarAgregarProducto.Enabled = false; //Definir el nombre de tu botón
```

Espero que esto te haya ayudado a solucionar tu problema